# How to access flutter jni `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/` folder

Tags: android, flutter, dart, java-native-interface

You need to read data from a file that exists in the path `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/`. There is no problem in checking the existence of a file. But I access this path with 'jni' i.e. 'C' code and read the data from the file.

Failed to open file due to permission problem.

Is there a way to access files in `/storage/emulated/0/Documents/` in jni C?

**permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

//in <application...
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
android:preserveLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

**code**

```
int nResult = (i ~/ 100) * 100;
File agingFile = File("/storage/emulated/0/Documents/$nResult/$i.C03");

await platform.invokeMethod("readFile", agingFile.path);

///JAVA
if(call.method.equals("readFile")){
   String path = call.arguments();
   ReadFile(path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the permission explicitly with handler_permission like that:

```
final bool granted = await Permission.manageExternalStorage.isGranted;
if (!granted) {
  await Permission.manageExternalStorage.request();
}
```